# Gem install producing "OpenSSL" error

Tags: openssl, ruby, gem

For at least a week now i have been trying to install Bettercap on my Raspberry PI using gem but whenever i type in:

```
sudo gem install bettercap
```

i receive an error message that says

```
 ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Unable to require openssl, install OpenSSL and rebuild ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources
```

Every fix that has been suggested to other people yields no results:

**Option 1: "http option"**

According to the answer by [Filippo De Bortoli](https://askubuntu.com/users/270523/filippo-de-bortoli) in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513369/openssl-installed-but-ruby-unable-to-require-it) on the same issue, disabling the https protocol will solve it. However after running these commands:

```
gem source -r https://rubygems.org/ 
gem source -a http://rubygems.org/
```

I still get this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
        Unable to require openssl, install OpenSSL and rebuild ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources
```

**Option 2: rebuild**

As suggested by [Filippo De Bortoli](https://askubuntu.com/users/270523/filippo-de-bortoli) in the [same thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513369/openssl-installed-but-ruby-unable-to-require-it) he reinstalled ruby after installing OpenSSL, however my raspbian came with OpenSSL and running `sudo apt-get install openssl` only confirms i have the latest version. I have also re-built ruby 3 times since i started getting this.

**Option 3: install locally**

After finding out that you could install the gems locally i installed the source and ran.

```
sudo gem install --local bettercap-1.6.2b.gem
```

and got the output:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'em-proxy' (>= 0.1.8, ~> 0.1) in any repository
```

I am guessing since it is only searching the local disk it can not find the dependencies it needs, so i decided to locally install "em-proxy" only to find it needed dependencies, which also needed dependencies. Great. So i decided to leave it for the sake of my sanity and it was overall impractical.

---

To wrap up, **how do i get rid of this error or at the very least bypass it?**

Just in case you wanted to know here is the output of `gem -v`:

```
2.4.5
```

and the output of `ruby -v`:

```
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [armv6l-linux-eabihf]
```

Answer (score 0):

Was struggling with this as well when compiling ruby 2.3.6 from source on Debian/Ubuntu. Solved it by install `pkg-config` additionally to `libssl-dev`, e.g. the full instructions:

`$ sudo apt install \
  make \
  gcc \
  pkg-config \
  libssl1.0-dev \
  libreadline-dev \
  libgdbm-dev \
  zlib1g-dev \
  libyaml-dev \
  libffi-dev \
  libgmp-dev \
  openssl
$ ./configure --disable-install-rdoc
$ make -j2
$ sudo make install`

Note, that the `libssl-dev` package is not compatible with `ruby2.3` (see: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3862#issuecomment-277512130) so on Debian/Stretch or Ubuntu/Xenial you need to install `libssl1.0-dev` instead.